# ASP.NET MVC Ajax error:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This seems simple enough but i am not able to get past the error i am receiving while creating cascading drop downs. I have visited this questions made changes from type: "GET" to type: "post", also in controller method i tried JsonResult and ActionResult. Everything seems right but still the error remains. The questions i checked are :[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877139/mvc-failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-500-internal),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597789/jquery-ajax-call-wont-access-the-controller-failed-to-load-resource-the-server),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318080/ajax-call-with-a-failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-o),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826641/server-responded-with-a-status-of-500-internal-server-error-when-using-ajax) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180684/failed-to-load-resource-the-server-responded-with-a-status-of-500-internal-ser) plus many tutorials and questions in other forums.

I am using VS2013 community with localdb and iis express

Following is my model:

```
public class ItemPrice
{
    public int ItemPriceID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }

    public virtual Item item { get; set; }
}
```

the controller action method is:

```
public JsonResult GetPriceByItemId(string ItemId)
    {
        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(ItemId);

        var prices = (from a in db.itemprice where a.ItemID == Id select a);

        return Json(prices, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

when debugging i made sure that the control is transferred at this method and query executes successfully.

the script:

```js
< script >
  $(function() {

    $('#ItemID').change(function() {

      $('#price').empty();

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetPriceByItemId", "StockIns")',
        datatype: "Json",
        data: {
          ItemId: $('#ItemID').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(index, value) {
            $('#price').append('<option value="' + value.ItemPriceID + '">' + value.price + '</option>');
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }); < /script>
```

i have debugged script in chrome developer tools and nothing looks wrong there. The error appears when loops in script starts to execute(or just before the execution of the loop.)

Comment: `return Json(prices.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: A 500 error means a server side problem, so you should set a breakpoint in the Action and debug that too.

Comment: @Satpal i tried it. In this case the loop in ajax execute once and i get undefined in dropdown.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan i debugged action in controller. No error and there i get expected results in  var prices.

Comment: Then are you sure it's this AJAX request that's causing the problem. You can't have a 500 error and return data from the same request

Comment: Seems that `$.each(data, function(index, value)` causing the error on client-side, assuming `price` is a drop down/select list. Also, you may include error element in ajax call to raise error into the page.

Comment: Debug your code. Open your browser tools (Network Tab) and inspect the response t see the details of the error. (and change the method parameter to `int ItemId` and send back an anonymous object containing only what you need, not the every property of the model - `var data = prices.Select(x => new { ItemPriceID = x.ItemPriceID, price = x.price }); return Json(data, ....);`)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan data is returned from controller but somehow at view i am not able to get data.

Comment: If your getting a `500(Internal Server Error)` the data is **not** being sent despite what you think. Use your browser tools to debug your code!